# Ĉu la vorto “motorfiakro” ekzistas?

Tags: word-choice

Laŭ [ĉi tiu kritiko de Esperanto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kV3lUddQFCs), ekzistas la vorto *motorfiakro* kiu havas la saman signifon kiel *taksio* kaj tio kaŭzas multe da konfuzo ĉar homoj lernas aŭ unu vorton aŭ la alian kaj tio kreas dialektojn kaj la du homoj ne povas komuniki inter si. Ŝajne mi lernis nur unu el tiuj dialektoj ĉar mi neniam aŭdis la vorton *motorfiakro*. Mi nek trovis ĝin en PIV nek Tekstaro. Ĉu ĝi vere ekzistas? De kie li trovis tiun vorton?

Comment: La vorto *Fiaker* (fiakro = kaleŝo) estas uzata nur en Aŭstrio. Uzi motorfiakro estas tre stranga, mi opinias.

Comment: Estas amuze ke en la angla _cab_ sinonimas _taksio_. Oni imagu ĉevalĉaron kun la gvidisto sidante antaŭe. Arkaisma termino.

Answer (score 5):

> **Artikoloj el Monato 2012-2018 (Tekstaro)**
>
> Fiakroj estas ĉevaltirataj ĉaroj, kiuj veturas tra la historia centro
>   de la urbo. La nomo fiakro devenas de la franca. En Parizo estis
>   atendejo de tiaj veturiloj en la strato Fiakro, kiu akiris sian nomon
>   de la monaĥo Fiakrius (Fiacrius).

Mi konkludas ke *motorfiakro* estas antikva kunmetaĵo kun simila senco de la pli moderna *taksio*. [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/fiakr.html#fiakr.motor0o) konfirmas ke ĝi estas arkaismo. *Fiakro* oficialiĝis en la dua Oficiala Aldono de la Akademio de Esperanto (1919) kaj *taksio* en la naŭa Oficiala Aldono (2007).

Mi trovas maltrafa la aserton *... tio kaŭzas multe da konfuzo ĉar homoj lernas aŭ unu vorton aŭ la alian kaj tio kreas dialektojn kaj la du homoj ne povas komuniki inter si*. La samo okazos inter du angloparolantoj se unu uzos vortojn de la epoko de Shakespeare kaj la alia nuntempan anglan (tio verŝajne neniam okazos, ĉar la tempoveturilo de *Back to the Future* ne plu ekzistas). Mi ne nomus tion dialekto, sed simple arkaika angla. [Dialekto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dialects_of_English) estas tio, kio okazas nuntempe en la angla (kaj aliaj lingvoj), sed malgraŭ tio ĝi prosperas. Mi pensas ke Esperanto nuntempe ne havas dialektojn. Miskomprenoj okazas pro aliaj kaŭzoj, ekz. malkutimo ĝin paroli aŭ manko de vortostoko. Miaopinie, la aŭtoro de tiu kritiko elektis tre malbonan ekzemplon por pravigi sian ideon.

Answer (score 1):

Me trovis ĝin en [*Majstro*](http://www.majstro.com/Web/Majstro/adict.php?gebrTaal=epo&bronTaal=eng&doelTaal=epo&teVertalen=taxi). Rimarku, ke ĝi aperas inter krampoj. Sed ankaŭ mi neniam aŭdis aŭ legis tiun vorton.

Krome, ĝi estas en [*ReVo*](http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/fiakr.html#fiakr.motor0o), kiu markas ĝin arĥaismo.

---

Mi ja trovis ‘fiakro’ kiel tradukon de *cab* in la vortaro de Wells; tamen la traduko de ‘fiakro’ laŭ Wells estas “(horse-drawn) cab”.